# Is there any need ,during programme of hibernate in eclipse ,its need net connection?

Tags: hibernate

My question is ,I am trying to solve my error like in hibernate with eclipse

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration:
>   /hibernate.cfg.xml

While same code when I run with netbeans there is no any such kind of error?

Why does this occur with eclipse when I connect with internet and doesn't show me such kind of error but when I become offline it show me error while it does not show me error in netbeans?

Can any one please suggest me why it occurs?

Comment: Are you using `Maven`? Maybe when offline you cant download your dependencies and that's why it fails.

Comment: No i am simply insert the value into the  database using eclipse ,am not using mavan project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It is because Hibernate jars are not available in build path in eclipse workspace.
Please check in buildpath whether hibernate jar is available or not